# Is there an adjectival form of “levity”?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Can anybody tell me the adjectival form of *levity*? I've found *levitious* [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Levitious&defid=4034126), but not sure whether it’s a dictionary word.

Comment: You're right to be suspicious of the source you quote, useful though it sometimes might be. 118 Google hits (according to my research) argue strongly against _levitious_ being acceptable - especially since many seem to be repeats of the Urban Dictionary reference. I'd say that _there is no accepted adjective_ corresponding to _levity_. Rephrasing, or choosing _frivolous_, _flippant_, _light_, _lighthearted_, _playful_ ... as appropriate, addresses the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because *levity* means “lightness” and ultimately derives from Latin *levis* meaning “light”, the best adjective that corresponds to it is probably just plain ***light***.

A conversation full of *levity* would therefore be a *light* conversation.

Comment: '*The Light Princess*' (now playing at the National Theatre) is built around a pun on *levity* as opposed to *gravity*, and *levity* as opposed to *seriousness*. It was written by Tori Amos based on a fairytale by George Macdonald, so has an impeccable background. (And yes, I would recommend it but this comment is not sponsored.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @tchrist: just use ***light***.

However, other possibilities are *frivolous*, *flippant*, or *giddy*, depending on what you want to convey.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help but wonder whether the word 'facetious' could be used as an adjectival term for 'levity'. The definitions are quite similar but I'm tentative about it's application.

(sourced from Dictionary.com so I'll leave it to you as an individual in determining it's credibility)

levity
ˈlɛvɪti/
noun
noun: levity; plural noun: levities

```
1.
the treatment of a serious matter with humour or lack of due respect.
```

facetious
fəˈsiːʃəs/
adjective
adjective: facetious

```
1.
treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humour
```

I think there is a correlation between the two definitions the only ambiguity is of course one is the treatment of a matter (ostensibly an ongoing situation) whilst conversely the term facetious deals with issues (so I'm assuming -and witnessed- it only being used during esoteric conversation/debate)

I'm not adamant about it but thus far this is the only option I'm aware of (of course there will be a far more efficient word that you'll stumble upon later in life) but hopefully this should do for now :)

Comment: As an individual, I will say that “levity” and “facetious” do not bear the same connotation in my mind. While the former is understood to lighten something that is not (and cannot be, if this word is appropriate) light to begin with, the latter describes a significantly more pointed irreverence.